# Git forgot to add file change to a not yet pushed commit (not the last one)

Tags: git

I want to add a file change to a not yet pushed commit (not the last one).

Let's say I have the following scenario:

```
git init
touch test.txt
// do some changes to the text file
git commit -a -m "First change"

# if I now change something I can add it to the previous commit with:
git add test.txt
git commit --amend -C HEAD


# more changes to test.txt
git commit -a -m "Second change"

# more changes to test.txt
git commit -a -m "Third change"

# one more change
# how can I add the change to my second commit (second change)?
```

I hope the question is clear. If not, let me know. I tried `git commit --amend -C HEAD~2`, but that one caused some weird trouble in my real git project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `git rebase`.  I would recommend reading up on `git help rebase` and especially the `INTERACTIVE_MODE` section as it is wise to be careful while performing the rebase.

Assuming your last commit was "Third change" you could:

1. Invoke `git rebase -i HEAD~2`
2. git will invoke your editor with two lines showing the second and third commits, with a "pick" prefix on each.  Change the "pick" prefix for your "Second change" commit to "edit".  It should then look like:

> ```
> edit xxxxxxx Second change
> pick xxxxxxx Third change
> ```

1. Save and exit your editor.
2. You will now be rolled back to a state "right after the second change" and git will stop to allow you to edit/amend the commit.  So you can now `git add` other files and once you're ready do a `git commit --amend` which will load up an editor where you can edit the second change's commit log message.
3. Once you're happy with the new "Second change", issue a `git rebase --continue`.  This will replay the third change over your revised second change.